# X-ray Like? (Blender 3.6 ViewPort)

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, edit-mode

I've downloaded the Blender 3.6 version, and I noticed when I got to edit mode. The viewports seems to be in a X-ray like mode, not sure what this thing called. But, do you know how to disable it? It's so annoying lol.

[image]

Comment: Maybe in the N panel > View > View, tweak the Clip Start and End values?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if this was just a bug or an intentional feature of Blender 3.6's initial release, but after installing the latest 3.6.2 LTS release, I have noticed that everything now looks normal. I do agree that this was incredibly annoying! Although I will also mention that the Clip values that User moonboots mentioned, specifically Clip Start, can cause some strange X-ray effects with faces if you have the value lower than 0.001 and are zoomed in quite close.